# What are the major factions and players on the Magic and the Science side?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun

There are various factions that exist on both the Magic and Science side, but what are the most prominent ones and who are their most well-known members?

Comment: This is tough to answer. Do you want to know only for the anime? Or also for the Novel? Also, the "major factions" switch from arc to arc. The only constant thing really is Touma (although the anime might make it seem like the Anglican Church is involved all the time, which is not the case).

Comment: I'd like as complete of a list as possible, just the anime is fine, but bonus points if you can include the light novel factions, too. By major factions I probably mean prevalent and currently active factions in the story, like the Board of Directors, Anglican and Roman Orthodox Church, ITEM, SCHOOL, and Skill Out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a generalized list of the people and faction in both the anime and manga continuity (including a bit from the light novels).

### Magic Side

**Roman Catholic Church**

- [Matthai Reese](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Matthai_Reese), *Pope*
- [Biagio Busoni](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Biagio_Busoni), *Bishop*
- [Ridovia Lorenzetti](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Lidvia_Lorenzetti), *Mardi Gras*

# God's Right Seat

- [Fiamma of the Right](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Fiamma_of_the_Right)
- [Acqua of the Back](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Acqua_of_the_Back)/William Orwell, *Flere210* ([Saint](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Saint))
- [Vento of the Front](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Vento_of_the_Front)
- [Terra of the Left](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Terra_of_the_Left)

**Russian Orthodox Church**

- [Nikolai Tolstoy](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Nikolai_Tolstoy), *Archbishop*

# Annihilatus

- [Vasilisa](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Vasilisa), *Head of Annihilatus*
- [Sasha Kreutzev](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Sasha_Kreutzev)

**Anglican Church**

- [Laura Stewart](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Laura_Stuart), *Archbishop*
- [Orsola Aquinas](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Orsola_Aquinas)

# The Church of Necessary Evil (Necessarius)

- [Kaori Kanzaki](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kanzaki_Kaori), *Salvare000* (Saint)
- [Stiyl Magnus](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Stiyl_Magnus), *Fortis931*
- [Index Librorum Prohibitorum](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Index_Librorum_Prohibitorum), *Dedicatus545*
- [Tsuchimikado Motoharu](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Tsuchimikado_Motoharu), *Fallere825*
- [Sherry Cromwell](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Sherry_Cromwell), *Intimus115*

# (Roman Catholic, London Branch) Agnese Forces

- [Agnese Sanctis](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Agnese_Sanctis), *Leader*
- [Angelene](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Angelene)
- [Lucia](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Lucia)

# Amakusa-Style Remix of Church

- Kaori Kanzaki, *Pontiff/Priestess*
- [Tatemiya Saiji](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Tatemiya_Saiji), *Substitute Supreme Pontiff*
- [Itsuwa](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Itsuwa)
- [Uragami](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Uragami)

**Knights of England**

- ["Knight Leader"](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Knight_Leader), *Leader*

**British Royal Family**

- [Elizard](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Elizard), *Queen of England*
- [Riméa](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Rim%C3%A9a), *Princess of England* (Oldest)
- [Carissa](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Carissa), *Princess of England* (Second-Oldest)
- [Villian](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Villian), *Princess of England* (Youngest)
- [Silvia](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Silvia), *Head Maid of the Royal Family* (Saint)

**Mercenarys**

- [Oriana Thomson](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Oriana_Thomson), *Basis104*

---

### Science Side

**Board of Directors**

- [Aleister Crowley](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Aleister_Crowley), *General Superintendent*
- [Kaizumi Tsugutoshi](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kaizumi_Tsugutoshi), *Chairman*
- [Oyafune Monaka](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Oyafune_Monaka), *Chairwoman*
- [Shiokishi](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Shiokishi), *Chairman*
- [Thomas Platinaburg](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Platinaburg), *Chairman*
- [Kumokawa Seria](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kumokawa_Seria), *Advisor*

**Hound Dog**

- [Kihara Amata](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kihara_Amata), *Commander*

**Misaka Network**

- [Misaka Imouto](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Misaka_10032), *Subject No. 10032*
- [Last Order](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Order), *Subject No. 20001*

**A Certain Magical High School**

- [Kamijou Touma](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kamijou_Touma), *Imagine Breaker* (Level 0)
- [Himegami Aisa](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Himegami_Aisa), *Deep Blood* ([Gemstone](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Gemstone))
- Tsuchimikado Motoharu, *Auto-Rebirth* (Level 0)
- [Aogami Pierce](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Aogami_Pierce)
- [Tsukuyomi Komoe](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi_Komoe), *Chemistry Teacher*
- [Oyafune Suama](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Oyafune_Suama), *Math Teacher*
- [Yomikawa Aiho](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Yomikawa_Aiho), *P.E. Teacher*

**Tokiwadai Middle School**

- [Misaka Mikoto](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Misaka_Mikoto), *Electromaster* (Level 5 Esper, No. 3)
- [Shirai Kuroko](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Shirai_Kuroko), *Teleporter* (Level 4)
- [Shokuhou Misaki](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Shokuhou_Misaki), *The Queen of Tokiwadai*, *Mental Out* (Level 5 Esper, No. 5)
- [Kongou Mitsuko](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kongou_Mitsuko), *Aero Hand* (Level 4)
- [Wannai Kinuho](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Wannai_Kinuho), *Hydro Hand* (Level 3)
- [Awatsuki Maaya](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Awatsuki_Maaya), *Float Dial* (Level 3)

**Sakugawa Middle School**

- [Uiharu Kazari](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Uiharu_Kazari), *Thermal Hand* (Level 1)
- [Saten Ruiko](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Saten_Ruiko), *Aero Hand* (Level 0)

**SCHOOL**

- [Kakine Teitoku](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kakine_Teitoku), *Dark Matter* (Level 5 Esper, No. 2) ([Awakened](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Awakening))
- ["Girl in the Dress"](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Girl_in_dress), *Measure Heart* (Level ?)
- ["Boy with Goggles"](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Boy_with_goggles)

**GROUP**

- [Accelerator](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Accelerator), *Vector Change* (Level 5 Esper, No. 1) (Awakened)
- Tsuchimikado Motoharu
- [Musujime Awaki](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Awaki), *Move Point* (Level 4)
- [Etzali](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Etzali)

**ITEM**

- [Mugino Shizuri](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Mugino_Shizuri), *Meltdowner* (Level 5 Esper, No. 4)
- [Takitsubo Rikou](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Takitsubo_Rikou), *AIM Stalker* (Level 4)
- [Kinuhata Saiai](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kinuhata_Saiai), *Offense Armor* (Level 4)
- [Hamazura Shiage](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Hamazura_Shiage), *Grunt, Chaffeur, and Informant*

**MEMBER**

- ["Professor"](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Professor), *Leader*
- [Baba Yoshio](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Yoshio_Baba)
- [Xochitl](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Xochitl)
- [Saraku](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Saraku), *Kill Point* (Level ?)

**BLOCK**

- [Saku Tatsuhiko](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Saku_Tatsuhiko), *Leader*
- [Teshio Megumi](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Teshio_Megumi)

**Judgement**

- [Konori Mii](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Konori_Mii), *177th Branch Office Chief*, *Clairvoyance* (Level 3)
- Shirai Kuroko
- Uiharu Kazari

**Skill Out**

- [Hattori Hanzou](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Hattori_Hanzou), *Leader (Temporary)*

# Big Spider

- [Kurozuma Wataru](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kurozuma_Wataru), *Founder, Former Leader*
- [Hebitani Tsuguo](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Hebitani_Tsuguo), *Second Leader*

**Anti-Skill**

- Yomikawa Aiho, *Lieutenant, Branch 73*
- [Tessou Tsuzuri](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Tessou_Tsuzuri)
- [Saigou Ryouta](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Saigou_Ryouta)

**Kihara Family**

- [Kihara Gensei](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kihara_Gensei)
- [Therestina Kihara Lifeline](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Therestina_Kihara_Lifeline), *(Former) Captain of MAR*
- Kihara Amata, *Leader of Hound Dog*

**Imaginary Number District**

- [Kazakiri Hyouka](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Kazakiri_Hyouka), *Counter Stop*

**Unaffiliated**

- [Sogiita Gunha](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Sogiita_Gunha), *Attack Crash* (Level 5 Esper, No. 7) (Gemstone)

---

### Other Side

- [Gabriel](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Archangel_Gabriel), *Archangel*
- [Aiwass](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Aiwass), *DRAGON*